# Break down hemoglobin into heme

Tags: organic-chemistry

Is there chemical that can break down the red blood cells/hemoglobin into smaller protein sub units/globins?

I would like to extract the [heme](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heme) molecules from the blood but not necessarily purify it,or separate it.I would like to get solution containing liberated heme units,its not problem if other stuff,like proteins and globins are floating in that solution,I just want to detach the heme part from the protein.Heme is iron containing coordination complex that binds to oxygen and give blood its red color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the chemical you are talking about that can break down the red blood cells/hemoglobin into heme and globins is carboxymethyl cellulose (CMC; see [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboxymethyl_cellulose)). There is a US patent claiming a method for separating blood hemoglobin into heme and globin from blood cells. The abstract states that:

> The invention relates to a method of dividing blood hemoglobin into heme and globin by suspending blood cells, separated from blood, in an acid aqueous solution, by precipitating the heme by means of carboxymethyl cellulose, and by separating the precipitated heme-CMC complex out from the aqueous solution of globin.

Title of the patent: Method for dividing blood hemoglobin into heme and globin

[Patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4518525): Karin Autio, Martti Kiesvaara, and Yrjö Malkki, *US Patent* 4,518,525, **1985** (11 pages)